# web api receive object with null variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have webforms asp and web api. In web forms I try send to web api object of class this way:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientHeader("", login, ClassMd5Calc.CalculateMd5Hash(password));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
UserTariff userTariff = new UserTariff();
userTariff.Login = "some value";
userTariff.Password = "some value";
userTariff.TariffName = "some value";
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(userTariff);
StringContent content = new StringContent(json);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/ChangeTariff/", content).Result;
```

This is my class (exist in data contract solution, so both project are use this class).

```
[Serializable]
public class UserTariff
{
    public String Login { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public String TariffName { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

My web api receive package, but all field are null. What's wrong? How it's fix?

```
public class ChangeTariffController : ApiController
{
    public void Post([FromBody] UserTariff mes)
    {
        //mes exist, but his property are null: mes.Login=null; mes.Password=null  and e.t.c. but need value: "some value"
```

**UPDATE 1.**

I also tryed this code, but it show same error:

```
                var content = new ObjectContent<UserTariff>(new UserTariff(), new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/ChangeTariff/", content).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the object content instead of the string content and should be using json media type formatter. This should fix the null bound variable in web api.

Also, use the newton soft json lib to convert the object to json.